# Porting OpenCV on WinCE07 platform

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, windows-ce

I have created a HOG based human detection code using OpenCV. While the code is runs well on my Windows 7 system, I now need to port this on a WinCE07 platform. How do I compile OpenCV for WinCE07 platform.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV site has instruction to build OpenCV from source, see ["Installation in Windows - Installation by Making Your Own Libraries from the Source Files"](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files).

Basically you need:

1. A suitable development environment for Windows CE (some years ago the environment was eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0, I do not know what Microsoft has now).
2. The source code of OpenCV.
3. CMake, it is the program for managing the build. CMake will create the [projects and solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384842.aspx) files. Usually CMake automatically recognize your development environment.